# How can I send a message from Java backend to Angular front end using websocket?

Tags: java, angular, websocket

I want to send messages from my server to the client, and thats it. No handshake, or anything, server sends and client receives and thats it.

I have the backend in Java, and my front end is in angular.

The following method builds the socket, and the host and port etc and sends a message.

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                String host = "localhost";
                int port = REDACTED;
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
               Socket socket = new Socket(address, port);
                //System.out.println("You're now connected to the Server"); /*this should only print once */
                //Send the message to the server
                OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

                String number;
                number=input.next();
                String sendMessage = number + "\n";
                bw.write(sendMessage);
                bw.flush();
                System.out.println("Message sent to the server : "+sendMessage);


            }
            catch (IOException exception)
            {
                //System.out.println("Server is still offline");/*This should only print once*/
            }
```

The issue is my Angular. I am not a web dev, and have no idea where my listener should be. I keep searching, but come across gradles/and pom.xml files etc, but I just need a simple listener on angular. I think it should be in index.html please correct me if im wrong. I basically need a simple angular listener that stores the message in a variable, thats it.

Comment: You can't initiate a WebSocket connection from server to client. Your client must connect the websocket, then your server can send messages back to the client.

Comment: @tkausl Wait so I have to get angular to connect to a websocket first then have angular send a message to my backend then my backend replies with the data?

Comment: You don't need to send any data from the client, but the client must open the connection. Also, WebSockets aren't a regular TCP-Stream. You need a WebSocket-Server.